# Remix: test with specific address

Tags: solidity, tokens, remix, addresses

In remix I included the following code in an ERC-20 token:

```
address burnAddress = 0xbababababababababababababababababa;
```

The address is meant to send tokens to but the address itself will not be able to send funds to anyone else because there are conditionals in the `transfer` and `transferFrom` functions preventing it.

The reason for its existence is to lower the amount of coins in circulation.

**Question:**

In remix, you're able to run the compilation of the token and test it with different addresses, but I only see the ability to create a new address with the "+" button on the right of the word **Account**. Is there any way to specify an address in the Account dropdown?

[image]

Comment: A little off-topic, but why aren't you using a typical `burn` strategy where you just subtract the tokens from the burner's balance and the total token supply?

Comment: E.g. https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/BurnableToken.sol.